# unable to toggle read-only mode in emacs

Tags: emacs

I am using `emacs-live` as my `emacs` starter config. I have `.jade` files which when opened in emacs say `Buffer is read only`.

However these same files I am able to edit in Sublime Text.

I tried toggling the read only by <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd> to no effect.

How do I resolve it ?

Comment: Do C-h w toggle-read-only RET to see related key-binding.

Answer (score 2):

File permissions shouldn't prevent Emacs from allowing you to toggle the read-only state of an associated buffer.

Can you try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `toggle-read-only` <kbd>RET</kbd> instead, to check whether it's the function or just the key binding that isn't working?

I'm assuming that <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd> *is* working in general for other buffers?

Comment: `toggle-read-only` is an obsolete alias for `read-only-mode`